# How to get a certain part of a string array if it contains a value

Tags: java, android

```
String sArr = "ads,Distribution;8,0.1%;10,2.6%;15,2.3%";
String sStrip = sArr.replace(" ", "").split(";");
string sAp = {"7","8","9","10","11"};

boolean blC = Arrays.asList(sStrip).contains(sAp[1]); //this returns false...
String getPerc = ""; //If I use `.contains(sAp[3])` should return `2.6%`
```

Here is a sample app pseudocode:

```
for each `sAp`
     check to see if the `sAp` value exist in `sStrip`[0].
          if `sAp` exist in `sStrip`[0]
               get the second part of the found match

`sApp` = 7
`sStrip` doesn't have a 7... do nothing

`sApp` = 8
`sString does have a 8, return 0.1%

...
```

How can I get the value in `getPerc`

tried this, didn't work:

```
for(String s : sStrip) {
    if (sAp[3].contains(s)) {
        tes = s.split(",")[1];
    }
    else {
        tes = "0%";
    }
}
```

The `sAp[i]` matches the first section of `sStrip`. so `ads,8,10,15` not `Distribution,0.1%,2.6%,2.3%`.

Comment: You want the double value before % if the key exists, right?

Comment: Sure I can add the % myself

Comment: What's the output of "ads,Distribution;8,0.1%;10,2.6%;15,2.3%" supposed to be ?

Comment: That is the string, so for each `sAp` I want to test to see if the value exist in the string. If it does, only get the second part (e.g. `0.1%`)

Comment: Answer's updated, check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    String sArr = "ads,Distribution;8,0.1%;10,2.6%;15,2.3%";
    String[] sStrip = sArr.split(";");
    String[] sAp = {"7", "8", "9", "10", "11"};

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sStrip.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sAp.length; j++) {
            if (sStrip[i].contains(sAp[j])) {
                String value = sStrip[i].substring(sStrip[i].indexOf(",") + 1);
                result.add(value);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

In this case the output is : `0.1%, 2.6%`

Comment: I have to use `sAp` with an index `i` as I am looping through each `sAp`.

Comment: The second for loop is needed if I am currently at `sAp[i]` value? I want to check the splitted string array against the `sAp[i]` only.

Comment: actually you test every item in sAp with every item of sStrip, That's the why we use two for loop, I didn't change splitted array just add loops.

Comment: I am sorry I meant to say the `sAp[i]` matches the first section of `sStrip`. so `ads,8,10,15` not `Distribution,0.1%,2.6%,2.3%`. I think that should clear it up... So I am thinking I should split `sStrip` again and add the first index of each in another array.

Comment: I get it, yes that's what these lines of code do, did you run it?

Comment: Didn't work for me, it just shows the `2.3` for every entry.

Comment: The reason mine isn't working because I already have a parent loop which gives me the current index of `sAp` and is using `i` as the index. So for each pass I have to check to see if the current `sAp` index value has any entries in the `sSplit` array.

Comment: `tes = limits.size() + " " + limits.get(1) + " " + strAPI[i] + " " + (limits.get(1) == strAPI[i]);` `//displays 11 8 8 false` Any idea why it would be false and not true?

Comment: Because you're using == for compare, Try equals method instead